# Why do these examples not in 5NF exhibit update problems?

Tags: normalization

The tables below (Fig 17.20) were extracted from the book 'An Introduction to Database Systems' by C. S. Date, v. 1 -Longman Higher Education (1985) 4th edition.

I don't understand the need for normalization up to the fifth normal form in the example cases.

Why do these examples exhibit update problems (Fig. 17.20)? (

[image]

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: What do you mean by "Why" they exhibit? What do you want an answer to contain? How is "because they are not in 5NF" not an answer to that? Do you mean, what are examples of "update problems"? The book twice says "If ...". Those are the "update problems". **17.20 is titled "Examples of update problems".** How is that not an answer? What do you understand "update problems" to mean & what is your justification? PS What edition of the book? What exactly does the book say about the problems & where do you get lost?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please edit your post to ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Clearly show what you started with including definitions & rules & heuristics from the context including appropriate & credited quotes & paraphrasings (so your post is self-contained) & don't include what is not necessary & explain how/where you are 1st stuck. Please act on my earlier comments.

Comment: There are business rules you haven't given from the context that say that (in business terms) SPJ contains certain rows & doesn't contain certain other rows depending on the business situation and/or that because of them (in relational/algebraic/math terms) SPJ is always the natural join of certain projections of SPJ. But you don't give any of that. It will all be in the textbook exposition, which is why I already asked where you get lost in it. Even after you give needed context please don't expect us to (re)write an exposition with no idea what you misunderstand or do or don't understand.

Comment: Your edit didn't clarify what you are trying to ask & certainly didn't result in asking about the things you asked about in your now-deleted comment about the text in the images. This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

In simple terms, a join dependency in a database occurs when you can gather information from one table by combining data from two or more other tables. The fifth normal form (5NF) aims to organize tables efficiently, ensuring there are no unnecessary or redundant ways to obtain information through joins.

In the tables in the figure, there is no such join dependency. The tables appear to be joinable using City.

Having said, I am co-author of a database design book and when we considered mentioning 5NF, we ended up ditching it all together. Not that it is not important but it is impractical. In the real-world, even BCNF is often violated for convenience. Perhaps decades ago when storage was more expensive but today, I feel there is very little care for anything above 3NF.